# Reloading of layout causes Model to go empty (MVC4)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to show a table of results in my view by use of HttpPost, but my view always turns up empty.
I have found out by now that the httpPost action works and returns a result, but before completing the action, the layout is called again, where the RenderBody is called again. Once the RenderBody is done, the view contains an empty model again and results in the page showing up empty.

Looking for advice how to solve this issue! I broke my head on this for hours and don't seem to see the light...

The View code:

```html
@using MovieRental.DAL.Entities; @model List
<Movie>

  @{ ViewBag.Title = "MyRentedMovies"; }

  <h2>MyRentedMovies</h2>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12 column">
      <form id="frmmymovies" class="col-md-12">
        <input id="currentuserid" type="hidden" name="userid" value="@ViewBag.user.UserId">
      </form>

      <div id="mymovies" class="btn btn-primary">Show my rented movies</div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    @ViewBag.cost;
  </div>

  @if (Model != null) {
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row clearfix">
      <div class="col-md-12 column">
        <table id="" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Action</th>
              <th>Movie Title</th>
              <th>Release Date</th>
              <th>Storyline</th>
              <th>Location</th>
              <th>Movie Genre</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <th>Action</th>
              <th>Movie Title</th>
              <th>Release Date</th>
              <th>Storyline</th>
              <th>Location</th>
              <th>Movie Genre</th>
            </tr>
          </tfoot>
          <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model) {
            <tr>
              <td><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" movieId="@item.MovieId"></i>
              </td>
              <td>@item.MovieName</td>
              <td>@item.ReleaseDate</td>
              <td>@item.Storyline</td>
              <td>@item.Location.LocationName.ToString()</td>
              <td>@item.MovieGenre.GenreName.ToString()</td>
            </tr>
            }
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  } else {
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row clearfix">
      <div class="col-md-12 column">
        <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
          You currenty don't have any rented movies in your possession.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  }
```

The Controller code:

```html
       public ActionResult MyRentedMovies()
        {
            return View();

        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult MyRentedMovies(int userid) 
        {
            var myrentdetails = rentrep.GetAll().Where(e => e.UserId == userid);
            List<Movie> mymovies = new List<Movie>();

            foreach (var item in myrentdetails)
            {
                Movie movie = movierep.FindById(item.MovieId);
                mymovies.Add(movie);                
            }
            return View(mymovies);
        }
```

The JS script:

```js
$(function () {
    $('#mymovies').click(function () {
        //var user = $('#currentuserid').val();
        console.log('gethere');
        $.post('/useronly/myrentedmovies', $('#frmmymovies').serialize(), function (data) {
            if (data) {
                console.log(data);
                document.location = '/useronly/myrentedmovies';
            }
            else {
                console.log('error');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: As soon as you return the html you are calling `document.location = '/useronly/myrentedmovies';` and redirecting to the GET method.

Comment: I removed the "document.location" line, but there is no change in the behavior. When I run in debug, I see the post works and goes back to the view and fills the table via the Model, but after that, the layout's "renderBody" is running the same html page again and this time, because it is now the GET again I assume, the model turns up empty.
So it seems my JS is fine, but the problem arises when the GET method is called again because of the layout's renderbody call..?

Comment: Your script is not fine. Ajax calls stay on the same page. Your not doing anything with the html you returned (e.g. adding it to the DOM) so you don't see any change. But whats the point of all this. The only element in the form is a hidden field which seems to be something representing the current user. Why not put all the code that's in the POST method into the GET method and just render the view you want. The form element, script and POST method all seem pointless.

Comment: Thanks already for your explanations! I'm pretty new to MVC and still in the progress of understanding. I wanted to work simply with GET instead of POST actually, but simply couldn't figure out how I can pass a parameter (the UserID) to my controller method this way. I'll try to figure this out now.

Comment: You must have had the userID in the GET method. Your view sets the value of the hidden input using `@ViewBag.user.UserId` (although your GET method code does not set it so I assume you omitted some code). The name of the input is `currentuserid` but the POST method parameter is `userid` so it would have never worked anyway! Just move all the code in the POST method to the GET method and delete the form element, script and POST method. But first spend some time working through some basic MVC tutorials.